# Convert tsvector column back to a TEXT column?

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

Is it possible to convert a Postgres column of type tsvector back to a regular TEXT column?

I assume it's lossy, but how can I create a new column from my existing tsvector column with type TEXT? Having it create multiple variants of words in the TEXT column is fine.

All of my inserts to the existing column were done with `to_tsvector` so I don't have the original raw TEXT.

I can do `tsvector_to_array` to convert a `tsvector` back to a string array. I can then convert the array to a string with `array_to_string`.

e.g:

```
SELECT array_to_string(tsvector_to_array(ts_column), ' ') FROM mytable
```

However this doesn't generate the full words, only the lexemes (and I'd want the full words even if lossy).

Comment: as tsvector would remove information and the order isn't stored, so i am guessing never

Comment: Right, I understand that it's lossy but even if I can get unordered text back with full words - that'd be sufficient.

Comment: i am not seeing your problem our code produces a string, which has all the words in it, but it has nothing to do whith the source, depending what you have a s datasource see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4b9a8b46594ea3bc29f7841666fa0288

Answer (score -2):

Here ya go. It works for all my test cases.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tsvector_to_string(input tsvector)
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  result text := '';
  lexemes text[];
  indices int[];
  lexeme text;
  index int;
BEGIN
  FOR lexeme, indices IN
    SELECT alias, string_to_array(word, ',')::int[]
    FROM
    (SELECT
      trim(both '''' from split_part(word, ':', 1)) as alias,
      trim(trailing '}' from trim(leading '{' from split_part(word, ':', 2))) as word
     FROM
     unnest(string_to_array(input::text, ' ')) as word) as subquery
  LOOP
    FOREACH index IN ARRAY indices
    LOOP
      result := result || ' ' || lexeme;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN trim(leading ' ' from result);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As a note, I am a total PL/pgSQL novice. But I just wrote the logic in Javascript and then ChatGPT obligingly converted it to PL/pgSQL. It's a crazy world we live in nowadays. Javascript implementation for reference:

```js
function convertString(str) {
      const indexToString = {};
      str.split(" ").forEach((val, i) => {
        const [lexeme, indicesStr] = val.split(":");
        const indices = indicesStr.split(",");
        indices.forEach(index => {
          indexToString[index] = lexeme.replace(/'/g, "");
        });
      });

      return Object.keys(indexToString)
        .sort()
        .map(index => indexToString[index])
        .join(" ");
    }
```

Comment: What does it do? How does it work? What is the javascript you used?

Comment: If you can't explain how it works, you're not in a position to judge that it works great - which is [one of the reasons why ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned). If you would add the JS code to your answer, a subject matter expert at least might be able to judge whether the conversion was correct - and finally, whether your original algorithm makes any sense

Comment: Hahaha, I'm sorry I explained how the sausage was made. I think that's a bit ridiculous when the code is passing test cases and it's not _that_ hard to follow. Just string manipulation. Added the lovingly hand crafted JS version as a reference though.